# how to turn this loops to big-o notation

Tags: math, for-loop

The question:
For the pseudo-code given below with T, being the or instruction period to run the i-th line, provide total execution time in big-O notation.

```
// get a positive integer from input
if n > 10
  print "this might take a while"
for k=1 to n
  for j = 1 to k
    print k*j
print "Done!"
```

Actually I know what that code does but I can't understand how to type this in big-O notation?

EDIT: [loop as php](http://ideone.com/SCISbO)

Comment: No that is not. @Schwern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k=1 to n
  for j = 1 to k
    print k*j
```

The outer loop will iterate n times, that part is easy.  Since it does no work other than running the inner loop we can ignore it for the purposes of Big O calculation.  The inner loop will iterate `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... + n` times which is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) or `(n*(n+1))/2`.  Big O notation ignores constants, so that can be simplified to `O(n*n)` or `O(n^2)`.

It's worth noting that the worst, best and average case for this algorithm are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is run n*(n+1)/2, so it's O(n^2)

Comment: @Philosopher Yes, since O notation is an expression of how fast runtime will grow as n gets larger.  It's a tool for grouping together similar algorithms to allow gross comparison of runtimes, so it ignores constants.  However, I believe he got the formula wrong.

Comment: @Philosopher The formula `n*(n/2)` is incorrect for the runtime of the inner loop. It gives the series `0.5, 2, 4.5, 8, 12.5...`  The correct formula is `(n*(n+1))/2` which is `1, 3, 6, 10, 15...` Poignant that it comes out with the same O approximation as they both grow exponentially.

Comment: Hi, corrected the formula for completeness. Let me make some other corrections: both `N*N/2` and `N*(N+1)/2` grow *polynomially*, not exponentially. And Big O doesn't just discard constants - it ignores all lower order components in a sum. That's why the exact formula doesn't matter for complexity calculation. It's the highest order term that usually determines scaling. If you're multiplying, you can't discard lower complexity terms. I.e. average quicksort is `O(N * log N)`, not `O(N)`.